# Excel - Help copying the contents of a multi-line cell to a new sheet and separate row for each line item

Tags: excel, vba

EDIT: I over simplified/sanitized the description and added more context and updated example.

I need help splitting data from a multi-line cell on Sheet1 into multiple rows on Sheet2 - or within the same sheet would be fine too.
Sheet1 has a computer name column and filename column. The computer name is listed once, but the filename cell contains 3 - 10 filenames with details, then it lists the next file and details (path, used by service, file write allowed for groups). It skips a line and then lists the next filename and details.

```
Example of filename cell:

Column: File Name (Cell B1)
Cell B2 contents:
Path : C:\Users\Me1\FileX.exe
Used by services : Servicename X
File write allowed for groups : Groupname X

Path : C:\Users\Me1\FileY.exe
Used by services : Servicename Y
File write allowed for groups : Groupname Y

Path : C:\Users\Me1\FileZ.exe
Used by services : Servicename Z
File write allowed for groups : Groupname Z
```

I would like to have the data 1:1 in Sheet2 or same sheet, so that I can pivot out the results for the Computers and filenames. The filenames and info aren't separated by commas or anything easy like that. I would like to have "Path, Used by services, file write allowed" grouped together in a separate cell, or have columns for each with their corresponding values for each.

Sorry for any confusion, I know this one is a bit complicated.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Example:

```
Sheet1 - A2: TestPC
Sheet1 - B2: 
Path : C:\Users\Me1\FileX.exe
Used by services : Servicename X
File write allowed for groups : Groupname X

Path : C:\Users\Me1\FileY.exe
Used by services : Servicename Y
File write allowed for groups : Groupname Y

Path : C:\Users\Me1\FileZ.exe
Used by services : Servicename Z
File write allowed for groups : Groupname Z

Sheet2 - A2:TestPC
Sheet2 - B2:
Path : C:\Users\Me1\FileX.exe
Used by services : Servicename X
File write allowed for groups : Groupname X

Sheet2 - A3:TestPC
Sheet2 - B3:
Path : C:\Users\Me1\FileY.exe
Used by services : Servicename Y
File write allowed for groups : Groupname Y

Sheet2 - A4:TestPC
Sheet2 - B4:
Path : C:\Users\Me1\FileZ.exe
Used by services : Servicename Z
File write allowed for groups : Groupname Z
```

I started working on this project in VBA about 2 months ago, and had it creating a new row on the existing spreadsheet with the data I needed. However, I ran into issues looping through the rows and getting duplicates and ended up just throwing up my hands and moving on, settling for just counting the amount of times ".exe" appeared in a cell. Now I'm at a point where I need to pivot out the individual file counts.

Comment: Ok guys, I apologize, I realized I tried to simplify the description too much and need to add some context.

Comment: I suggest edit your question to include realistic simulated data as text which can be copy/pasted, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), along with a screenshot of your desired results from that data.

Comment: If that is alll you want, all you need to do in my code is change the Splitter delimiter from a single linefeed to a double linefeed :  `"#(lf)"` => `"#(lf)#(lf)"`. Of course, you still have only posted a single row, and you have not posted what you want for an end result. Yours is not a real good example for testing.

Comment: See my edited post taking into account your latest revisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

  - It is just a single relevant step in PQ: splitting on the linefeed.

*It would not surprise me if you could do the rest of your task easily in PQ also*

[image]

```
let

//change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table7"]}[Content],

//Split column by the linefeed into rows
//  The Computer Name will automatically fill
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(
        Table.TransformColumns(Source, {
            {"File Name", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("#(lf)", QuoteStyle.Csv), 
            let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "File Name")
in
    #"Split Column by Delimiter"
```

[image]

Your revised data, ***and also adding a second row to your data***
[image]

And by changing the `Splitter` argument to reflect a double linefeed: `"#(lf)" => "#(lf)#(lf)"`

Results in: 
[image]

However, if you want to make the individual items appear as separate columns, and assuming (since you didn't specify) that the columns would be named by the part of the string to the left of the initial colon, then the code becomes a bit more complex:

```
let

//change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table7"]}[Content],
//Split column by the linefeed into rows
//  The Computer Name will automatically fill
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(
        Table.TransformColumns(Source, {
            {"File Name", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("#(lf)#(lf)", QuoteStyle.Csv), 
            let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "File Name"),

//Generate Lists of column values and headers
//  then create a table from those lists
    #"Split Lines" = Table.AddColumn(#"Split Column by Delimiter", "Tables", (r)=>
        let 
            Fields = List.Accumulate(
                Text.Split(r[File Name],"#(lf)"),
                {},
                (s, c) => s & {Text.Trim(Text.BeforeDelimiter(c,":",0))}),
            Values = List.Accumulate(
                Text.Split(r[File Name],"#(lf)"),
                {},
                (s, c) => s & {{Text.Trim(Text.AfterDelimiter(c,":",0))}})
        in 
            Table.FromColumns(Values, Fields)),

//Remove unneeded Column
// and expand the tables
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Split Lines",{"File Name"}),
    colHdrs = List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(#"Removed Columns"[Tables], each Table.ColumnNames(_)))),
    #"Expanded Tables" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Tables", 
        colHdrs),

    #"Type as Text" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Tables", 
        List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(#"Expanded Tables"), each {_, type text}))
   
in
    #"Type as Text"
```

***Results***
[image]

Comment: This worked great, thank you! Can we add a slight tweak please? I'd like to keep the data to the left of the colon too. "Path" and "Used by Service" could remain as headers, but can we make the 3rd header be "Permissions".  Or they could all just be generic1, 2, 3, and I can rename if needed. The permission values vary (ie: file write, full control, special, etc).  Sometimes there are 4+ lines of data bc a path/directory may have multiple incorrect permissions applied.

Comment: @John It is likely doable. But you've already changed the desired result once. And your description of what you want is still vague. I suggest that you work on modifying the code provided to accomplish whatever it is that you really want. If you are unsuccessful, then post a new question showing exactly what you want and what you tried.  And if a response to this question has answered your question as posted, you should mark it as the answer. Feel free to ping me if you post a new question on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, iCnt As Long
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range
    Dim arrRes, aVal, vFN
    ' Load data
    arrData = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    ' Count output rows
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        iCnt = iCnt + UBound(Split(arrData(i, 2), Chr(10))) + 1
    Next
    ReDim arrRes(1 To iCnt, 1 To 2)
    iCnt = 0
    ' Loop through data
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        aVal = Split(arrData(i, 2), Chr(10))
        For Each vFN In aVal
            iCnt = iCnt + 1
            arrRes(iCnt, 1) = arrData(i, 1)
            arrRes(iCnt, 2) = vFN
        Next
    Next i
    ' Write output to sheet
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Resize(iCnt, 2).Value = arrRes
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.CurrentRegion property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.currentregion?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144111)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Split function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [Range.Resize property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: Hi Taller, this worked great for me as well. I ended up splitting the data on a diff character/string. Then just added a few commas and used the text to column feature in excel. Thank you!